# How to specify credentials when connecting to Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ads

I can connect to a domain's Active Directory using [ADsGetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
IADs domain;
ADsGetObject("LDAP://fabrikam.com", IADs, domain);
```

But how can I query active directory when I need to specify the credentials (i.e. the interactive user does not have permissions to query active directory, or is not a valid user in that domain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to bind With [ADsOpenObject and IADsOpenDSObject::OpenDSObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: i've never even *seen* `ADsOpenObject`, i'll have to test it to make sure it doesn't suffer the same problems as .NET's version (cannot connect if the user account doesn't have permission to read AD)